# Replacing multiple \r\n in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm having text like this:

`some text \r\n  \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n some text  \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n  some text  \r\n   \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n`

I need to replace each block of multiple `\r\n` with just one `<br/>`

I tried to use `str_replace('\\r\\n','<br/>',$text);` but I ended up with too many `<br/>`

I need the final output to be like this:

`some text <br/> some text <br/> some text <br/>`

Answer (score 6):

Use a regex with a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:\r\n *)+/', '<br />', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:   # Start a group which matches:
 \r\n # one newline combination
 [ ]* # followed by zero or more spaces
)+    # Repeat the entire group once or more, as many times as possible
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [regular expressions](https://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
$output = preg_replace(',(\r\n)+,', '<br />', $input);
```